# "Один из самых знаменитых сюжетов, основанный на реальных событиях"?

Tags: согласование

О [Беатриче Ченчи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8,_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5)

> **Один из самых знаменитых трагических сюжетов, основанный на реальных событиях**, происшедших в конце XVI века в знаменитой римской семье,
>   был интерпретирован очень разными и талантливыми писателями, на
>   протяжении столетий. Шелли, Дюма, Стендаль, Уайльд, Арто, Моравио –
>   лишь краткий перечень тех художников слова, кто сохранил эту историю и
>   донёс некоторые из тех страшных фактов до наших дней.

Один из сюжетов - основанный? Я то правлю на "основанных", то возвращаю к как было. Мне ни так ни сяк не читается...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но ведь такое согласование возможно, это автор решает, какой смысл: если один сюжет основан на реальных событиях, остальные просто знамениты, то единственное число, если все знаменитые сюжеты на реальных событиях, то лучше множественное, чтобы не путать читателя.Мне кажется, все на реальных событиях, но точно не знаю.

Comment: А с чем будет согласовано ***основанный***? По авторскому замыслу именно так.

Comment: Один из... сюжетов (=1 сюжет), основанный... , был интерпретирован... Всё нормально.

Comment: Да, верно, ведь подлежащее - один из сюжетов, а не просто один.